# On Android, is there an intent that will open the call history for a specific phone# (or contact)?

Tags: android

I'm not sure if there's a platform intent for the OS in general, or if it may be app-dependent (for something like the AOSP Dialer or Google Phone apps), but I'd like to be able to generate an intent to open directly to a specific caller's call history.

I'm already able to send an intent to simply open the call log, but I can't find any way to open the history for a specific phone#. I've also tried to query the `CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_FILTER_URI`, retrieving the ID of the specific call, and then using the `CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI` with that ID being appended, but again, that just opens the call log, not the specific call details:

```
Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
   setDataAndType(
       Uri.withAppendedPath(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, id),
       CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_TYPE
)}
```

I've done my testing on both the emulator and a real device, with both the AOSP Dialer and Google Phone apps. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?